# The replica trick

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics

Assume that I have an interaction term of the form
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{a=1}^{M}g_i f_{i,a}^{\dagger}f_{i,a}\sigma_z $$

where the $g$'s are random and taken from the gaussian ensemble and
$f_{i,a}$ is some complex fermion.

In this case, is it valid to use the replica trick ? I am asking because the randomness is not between the different complex fermions on each site, but on different sites.

Comment: Hi, please provide a reference and explain what you want to do.